# Finding dissolved amount of base from pH and solubility product

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, ph, buffer

> Calculate the amount of $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ which is solubilized in $\pu{1.25 L}$ of a buffered solution at $\mathrm{pH} = 9.5$. $(K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{Mg(OH)2}) = \pu{5.61E-12})$.

From $\mathrm{pH}$ I compute the $\mathrm{pOH}$, so $[\ce{OH-}] = \pu{3.16E-5}$. But how can I compute $[\ce{Mg(OH)2}]$?

$[\ce{Mg}^{2+}]=\frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{[\ce{OH-}]^2}$ and then?

$[\ce{Mg(OH)2}]=[\ce{Mg^2+}]+[\ce{OH-}]^2$?

Comment: You compute [$\ce{Mg^2+}$] not [$\ce{Mg(OH)2}$] // You may find useful these links for text formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: I need $[\ce{Mg(OH)2}]$ for the solution, no?

Comment: If [$\ce{Mg^2+}$] is e.g. $\pu{1 mmol L-1}$, then $\pu{1 mmol}$ of $\ce{Mg(OH)2(s)}$ has been dissolved in 1 L of the buffer.

Comment: Thus $[\ce{Mg^2+}]=\frac{[\ce{OH-}]}{2}$, then $[\ce{Mg^2+}]=[\ce{Mg(OH)2}]$?

Comment: Neither, neither.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133123/discussion-between-rick88-and-poutnik).